# How many chapters(adhyayas) in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata

How many chapter (adhyaya)in parvas of Mahabharata?(gita press Mahabharata)
Note: chapters means not parva or sub-varna

Answer (score 1):

According to gita press edition , there are 2229 chapters (without harivamsha)

https://archive.org/download/unabridged-mahabharata-6-volumes-set-in-hindi-by-veda-vyasa-compressed

Comment: According to gita press